# Is there a way to sort portion of a line by shell script

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to come up with a way sort numbers for a line with numbers.

e.g., suppose there is a file that has

SERVERA;1234;12:E 13:W 15:E 16:E 17:E 18:E 25:E 26:E 28:E 29:E 30:E 31:E 32:E 36:R 39:E 43:E 46:E 47:E 67:E 76:E 78:E 86:E 87:E 88:E 89:E 90:E 92:E 93:E 95:E 98:E 100:E 112:E 116:E 117:E 128:E 131:E 134:E 135:E;SERVERA;SA;SA

SERVERB;1235;12:R 13:W 15:E 16:E 25:E 26:E 28:R 30:E 31:E 36:R 37:E 39:E 43:E 45:E 46:E 47:E 106:E 128:E 136:E 137:E;SERVERB;SB;SB

SERVERC;1236;30:E 28:R 12:E 13:E 15:E 16:E 17:E 25:E 26:E 36:R 37:E 39:E 43:E 45:E 46:E 47:E 78:E 89:E 106:E 112:E 128:E 136:E 137:E;SERVERC;SC;SC

In the line that starts with SERVERC, the numbers are not in incremental order and it is out of order.  I want to fix this from

SERVERC;1236;**30:E 28:R** 12:E 13:E 15:E 16:E 17:E 25:E 26:E 36:R 37:E 39:E 43:E 45:E 46:E 47:E 78:E 89:E 106:E 112:E 128:E 136:E 137:E;SERVERC;SC;SC

to

SERVERC;1236;12:E 13:E 15:E 16:E 17:E 25:E 26:E **28:R 30:E** 36:R 37:E 39:E 43:E 45:E 46:E 47:E 78:E 89:E 106:E 112:E 128:E 136:E 137:E;SERVERC;SC;SC

I heard there is ways to sort these by Java but I'm not very familiar with Java and so wondering if I can do this by shell scripting.  or Python if it's possible.

any clue will be appreciated.  many thanks

Comment: The `sort` utility works on lines, and the sort inside Python works on arrays. In both cases you would therefore do a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) by breaking up the string into pieces, sort those and then put them together again. Having said this, I personally would prefer doing it in Python instead in POSIX shell, but in the end, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

with bash, you can

```sh
(
  IFS=';'
  while read -ra fields; do
    fields[2]=$(echo "${fields[2]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -t: -k1,1n | paste -sd ' ')
    echo "${fields[*]}"
  done < file
)
```

or a perl one-liner

```sh
perl -F';' -ane '
  $F[2] = join " ", sort {$a <=> $b} split " ", $F[2];
  print join ";", @F
' file
```